# connect a springboot backend to a sql server db

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, database-connection

I'm trying to connect my springboot backend to a sql server data base without success.

I'm using Sql Server Managment. I've created an instance "LocalDB/MSSQLLocalDB" to host my db : "vitrinedb" and i'm using an SQL server authentication.

[MSSMS architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg9y9.png)

I've created a login as well : "springboot" with sysadmin server role, linked to "vitrindb", and mapped to a user "springbootuser" as shown below.

[login properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVCX2.png)

I'm sharing you the connection properties of my login as well :

[login connection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwWLk.png)

I'm sharing you my application.yml to configure the connexion on springboot side:

```
app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=vitrinedb;trustServerCertificate=true
    username: springboot
    password: *****
    pool-size: 30
```

When I launch my springboot app I get this code error :

SQL State  : S0001
Error Code : 18456
Message    : ╔chec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateurá'springboot'. ClientConnectionId:8e1db9be-a1a5-4faa-9be2-b3b75795798f

at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:74) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:140) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:140) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: ╔chec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateurá'springboot'. ClientConnectionId:8e1db9be-a1a5-4faa-9be2-b3b75795798f
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:300) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:133) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6299) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4911) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4849) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7620) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3916) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3358) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar:na]
... 29 common frames omitted

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be appriciated, Thank you !

Comment: I would start by connection a "plain" SpringBoot backed. It seems you are including Flyway in the stack, as well as containers. Keep it simple first. Once the connection works starts adding building block to the mix.

Comment: localhost? shouldn't it be localdb something. it looks like you're connecting to "real" sql server

Comment: Unless something's changed recently you can't use the JDBC driver with `jdbc:sqlserver://(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;...` because that driver only supports TCP/IP connectivity (and LocalDB requires named pipes). Refs: [LocalDB support #769](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/769), [Not able to connect to localDB from java connection string #1157](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1157).